# Javascript Media Query not working

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so this code does work (running the field required javascript) but I want it to only run on mobile so I am trying to add a media query to only run the javascript if its on a mobile (below 400px). Not sure if i've missed something silly or am doing it completely wrong.

```
function validateForm() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
    } else {        
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
    }   


    </script>
    <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reference [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/)

```
// media query event handler

if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 500px
    }
    else {
        // window width is less than 500px
    }

}
```